# Why is this Runge-Kutta 2nd order program printing out incorrect values?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I've recently posted a question about this code in relation to the concept behind it, but I've sorted that now. However, the code is printing out incorrect values and I can't spot why. Here's the code:

```
program rungekutta
implicit none
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
integer :: i
real(kind=dp) z, y, t
do i=1,100
call rk2(dydt, dzdt, z, y, t)
print *, z, y
end do

contains
subroutine rk2(z, y, t)
implicit none
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
real(kind=dp) :: k1y, k1z, k2y, k2z, n, h=0.1, y=1, z=0, t
k1y = dydt(y,z,t)*h
k1z = dzdt(y,z,t)*h
k2z = dzdt(y + (0.5*k1y), z + (0.5*k1z), t + (0.5*h))*h
k2y = dydt(y, z +(0.5*k1z), t)*h
y = y + k2y
z = z + k2z
end subroutine

function dzdt(y,z,t)
real(kind=dp) :: y, z, t, dzdt, omega=1, A=0, B, C=0, D=0
B = omega**2
dzdt = A*y**3 + B*y - C*z + D*sin(omega*t)
end function

function dydt(z)
real(kind=dp) ::  z, dydt
dydt = z
end function
end program
```

Here is a print screen of the terminal : https://prnt.sc/hchmv7

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So, what should be the correct values you would expect? Why are these incorrect? Please explain. Please try not to post pictures, but text instead. If you do not know how to copy text from Windows console, just search the web, it is very easy.

Comment: I suggest you to print also other values, like `k2y` and `k2z` (they are likely zero) to better understand what is going on during debugging. It is a technique I use in my work.

Comment: Does your code even compile? You can't set dummy arguments `z` and `y` during declaration in `rk2`, that is illegal. Please confirm the code you posted is an exact copy and that it compiles.

Comment: @VladimirF I've declared the values of z , y and t outside of the do loop in the main program now and I'm getting varying values, the last values printed are z = 0.559 and y = -0.831.  The values I expect are for z and y to oscillate between 0 and 1. Thanks!

Comment: Please update the question by [edit]. Both the code and tye results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you call rk2 with 5 arguments but declare it only with 3

Comment: I don't believe that it reflects the real code. The OP never updated the question, but the code would not compile with such an error. The code in the question is not the real code the OP was running. There more such errors there, notice my comments above.